# OpenKinect Java JNI error: libOpenKinect.so: undefined symbol: libusb_init

Tags: java, java-native-interface, kinect

I get the following error when making the [Java JNI Wrapper](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Java_JNI_Wrapper) for [OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page):

```
java: symbol lookup error: 
  /home/richard/libfreenect/wrappers/java/dist/libOpenKinect.so: 
  undefined symbol: libusb_init
```

I use the [Ubuntu Manual Install](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Ubuntu_Manual_Install) with the following exceptions:

- git://github.com/michael-nischt/libfreenect.git instead of git://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect.gitworks, because the JNI wrapper isn't integrated into the main distribution.
- freeglut3-dev instead of libglut3-dev.

I am able to run glview successfully.

I modify the build.sh script so that LIBFREENET_LIBRARY refers to the correct directory. The jar build then compiles successfully. The example file compiles correctly.

```
javac -d ./ -classpath .:./dist/OpenKinect.jar ./OpenKinect/src/Example.java
```

I get the error when I run:

```
java -Djava.library.path=./dist -classpath .:./dist/OpenKinect.jar Example
```

Has anyone else experienced this error?

Has anyone been able to resolve this error?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Comment: I managed to get it working but i've just reinstalled my laptop so I'mn in lib hell just now, once I get round to sorting this I'll post up what I did. (There where 2 jars that I needed for osx but I only had 1 in classpath as I recall)

Answer (score 0):

Verify the dependencies of the shared library libOpenKinect.so:

```
ldd /home/richard/libfreenect/wrappers/java/dist/libOpenKinect.so/libsample.so
```

You must find a line with `libusb-1.0.so.0`. If not this mean that the library is not link to libusb. A solution is to recompile the shared library with the flag `-lusb-1.0`: